# how to integrate fire base push notification in web application using Javascript

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) and tried to implement in HTML page but it did not work.

I created the FCM project and select the cloud messaging and select the web part. They provided the following file:

```
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.2/firebase.js"></script>
        <script>
          // Initialize Firebase
          var config = {
            apiKey: "BIzaSyCODqtGdk9xNYU4ifeWiUvnRyrWA_N6np0",
            authDomain: "checking-22492.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://testings-22492.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "checking-22492",
            storageBucket: "checkingwebdemo-22492.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "648493233490"
          };
          firebase.initializeApp(config);
        </script>
```

I have already integrated it into iOS and Android, Please suggest how it will work in the web application.